# Icons from i3bar are absent even though the processes are running

Tags: apt, i3-wm, top-bar

I am using Regolith (an i3-based WM) on Ubuntu `22.10`. I recently removed the `python3` package inadvertently (don't ask how), but after I had reinstalled `regolith-desktop`, the `i3bar` only shown my widgets (`time` and `battery`), all the icons have disappeared.

Using `ps` we can see the processes running. Software such as `flameshot`, `kdocker`, `nm-applet` are running but absent from the bar.

There is surely something to change in the configuration or a package that was not reconfigured properly.